# Why does `to_unsigned(0, 4) >= -1` evaluate to `FALSE` at runtime?

Tags: vhdl

Using the test code below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
architecture sim of tb is
begin
  process is
  begin
    for c in -1 to 1 loop
      assert to_unsigned(0, 4) >= c report "Fails: 0 >= " & integer'image(c) severity NOTE;
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Shows this output using ModelSim 10.5a:

```
Loading work.tb(sim)
** Note: Fails: 0 >= -1
   Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb
** Note: Fails: 0 >= 1
   Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb
```

So effectively `to_unsigned(0, 4) >= -1` evaluated to `FALSE`, and this is not reported at run-time when I used the `for` loop.  Why is this?

Note that if I write `to_unsigned(0, 4) >= -1` without using the `for` loop for getting the `-1` value at runtime, then the ModelSim compiler will report that "Value -1 (of type std.STANDARD.NATURAL) is out of range 0 to 2147483647.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL/DR : Please ask this wherever you get tech support for Modelsim, and update the question with their response.

A quick rewrite and a cross-check with the (generally pretty strict and accurate) ghdl simulator:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture sim of tb is
begin
  process is
  begin
    for c in -1 to 1 loop
      assert to_unsigned(0, 4) 
       >= 
       c 
       report "Fails: 0 >= " & integer'image(c) severity NOTE;
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

> ghdl -r tb
>   ./tb:error: bound check failure at tb.vhd:14
>   ./tb:error: simulation failed

shows a bound check error precisely at the evaluation of `c` which is not within the legal range for an Unsigned or Natural.

So the question is, did either ghdl or Modelsim pick an inappropriate `>=` operator?

The source for numeric_std shows only two `>=` operator definitions where the first argument is an `unsigned`. (This file is "copyright 2008" so for the VHDL-2008 standard.)

```
  -- Id: C.19
  function ">=" (L, R : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED) return BOOLEAN;
  -- Result subtype: BOOLEAN
  -- Result: Computes "L >= R" where L and R are UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED vectors possibly
  --         of different lengths.

  -- Id: C.23
  function ">=" (L : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED; R : NATURAL) return BOOLEAN;
  -- Result subtype: BOOLEAN
  -- Result: Computes "L >= R" where L is an UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED vector and
  --         R is a nonnegative INTEGER.
```

Neither of which permits a signed quantity (Signed or Integer) as the second argument.

So, you might want to look at the source for `numeric_std` in your installation to see if it's a different revision, with a `>=` operator permitting mixed Unsigned and Integer datatypes. I doubt it exists : it would be dangerously prone to just this sort of misunderstanding.

If there is no such operator, Modelsim is being permissive here; are there compilation options to turn on stricter compliance?

And if you think this is unnecessarily pedantic, consider this:

```
c := -1;
if to_unsigned(0, 4) >= c then
    emergency_stop;
end if;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.4 Function calls, para 5 (in part): *Evaluation of a function call includes evaluation of the actual parameter expressions specified in the call and evaluation of the default expressions associated with formal parameters of the function that do not have actual parameters associated with them. In both cases, the resulting value shall belong to the subtype of the associated formal parameter. ...* Shall indicates a mandatory requirement (1.3.1 para 4) despite Modelsim making it optional for performance purposes.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: There is no additional `>=` in my `numeric_std` package, and if I make my own similar function in the module or in a package, then the negative value is reported immediately.  So it looks like a performance optimization made by ModelSim for `numeric_std` only, as @user1155120 suggests.  I will not try to get this to Mentor, since it is almost impossible to start a support case for ModelSim; at least I do not have the required attention.